# parse push notification not working in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

first sorry for my bad English ,I am new to parse notification but it was not working any one please help me

mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ParseApp.java

```
public class ParseApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate();

        Parse.initialize(this, "appilicationId", "key");

        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL=new ParseACL();
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    }
}
```

reciver.java

```
public class Reciver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Push", "Clicked");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name=".ParseApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService"></service>
        <receiver  android:name="com.pop.pushnotifi.Reciver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>

            </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse push notifications are sent through GCM for supported devices so you need to also register with GCM.  This is directly from Parse Docs

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
    -->
    <category android:name="com.parse.starter" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And the permission:

```
<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Please see [here](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing) and [here](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) for a full guide to set up push correctly.